# jQuery : give preference to inner click

Tags: jquery, click, event-propagation

I have a big div with some links inside, I'd like to have the big div clickable AND links inside too, I did this :

```
html :

<div class="clickable">
  some text...
  <a href="myurl1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="myurl2">Link 2</a>
  some text...
</div>

jquery :

$('.clickable').click(function() {
   alert('Hello');
});
```

If I click on a link inside the clickable div, I got the 'Hello' alert first and then the new page is loaded : is that possible to get the anchors working without triggering the outer div click handler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/wPymp/

This code works in a simple way: [`.event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) makes sure the event does not propagate upwards across the DOM and trigger handlers on ancestor elements.

Comment: jsFiddle should be linked from the front page, of course with a list of competitors (I'm not affiliated with jsFiddle in any way).